# Looking for a Finite Difference scheme of the following form....

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences, lagrange-interpolation, pade-approximation

I'm having trouble deriving a finite difference scheme that calculates the second derivative of a function on the boundaries of a non-uniform grid and makes use of a known first derivative at the boundaries.

#### Notation

Suppose I have $N$ ordered points  ${x_i}$ ($i \in 1, 2, 3...N$) where $x_i < x_{i+1}$, and a function $f(x)$ evaluated at each of those $N$ points: $f_i \equiv f(x_i)$.

Suppose I also know the function's derivative at the endpoints: $g_1 \equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\big|_{i=1}$ and $g_N \equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\big|_{i=N}$.

#### Uniform Grid

IF the grid was uniformly spaced (say, with spacing $h$), a possible 1st order accurate scheme at $i=1$ is:

\begin{equation} 
   \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\big|_{i=1} \;=\; \frac{2}{h^2}\left(f_2 - f_1\right) - \frac{2}{h} g_1
\end{equation}

which can be derived from this Taylor expansion: $f(x+h) = f(x) + h f'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x)$, which in our notation is: $f_2 = f_1 + h g_1 + \frac{h^2}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\big|_{i=1}$

#### Non-Uniform Grid

Is there a finite difference scheme to calculate the second derivative at the endpoints in a form like this?

\begin{equation} 
   \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\big|_{i=1} \;=\; A g_1 + B f_1 + C f_2 + D f_3 + E f_4\text{,}
\end{equation}

where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and $E$, are all constants that depend on the grid spacing.

Comment: @hardmath: I am implicitly solving a PDE similar to the Poisson equation with Neumann-type boundary conditions. I need to approximate the second derivative at the boundaries. While I use a five point stencil in the interior ($x_{i-2}$ to $x_{i+2}$, this is not an option at the boundaries. The boundary conditions give me values for the first derivatives at the boundaries, and I would like to use these known values to help constrain the second derivatives at these points. Does this help? I can provide further details if you wish.

Comment: @hardmath: I've been trying to solve my PDE on an irregular grid for months. It is well-posed and has a unique solution. Unfortunately, it is poorly-conditioned, and most of this is due to the constraints on the boundaries. I experimented with a uniform grid and found that if I treat the boundaries as described in my question (above, under "Uniform Grid"), rather than using a *sided* FD method for the 2nd derivs at the boundaries, the condition number for my matrix went down considerably and I began to get good results. I'm having trouble finding/deriving the version for my irregular grid.

Comment: That helps.  You want to impose the Neumann-type boundary conditions.  A typical way to do this with finite difference approximations is through "ghost points", a discussion of which is found in [Sec. 2 of this PDF](http://www.math.uci.edu/~chenlong/226/FDM.pdf).  Imposing the second-order PDE "at the boundary" can be problematic with some functions.  The [Computational Science SE Community](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) may provide a more concentrated expertise in this topic.

Comment: @hardmath: Thanks! Perhaps I'll ask it over there, too. I'm quite familiar with using ghost points. (The expression I gave for a uniform grid can actually equivalently be derived from using ghost points!) I actually kind of expect ghost points will be used to derive the non-uniform expression. I'm just not sure of the best way to combine everything for the non-uniform grid.

Comment: It would be better to ask the moderators to migrate the Question, if you do not get a solution here within a week or so.  It is worth clarifying what drives the need for a non-uniform grid, since being "non-uniform" is not nearly as informative to Readers as specifying a uniform grid.  For example, is there a convenient spatial transformation that takes your non-uniform grid and makes it uniform?

Comment: You formula for the uniform grid is only of the first order. 
$$
\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h^2} - \frac{2}{h}f'(0) = f''(0) + \frac{h}{3} f'''(0) + O(h^2)
$$

Comment: @uranix: Nice catch! Thanks! I thought that because I had used this 2nd order accurate expansion ($f(x+h) = f(x) + h f'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2}f''(x) + \mathcal{O}(h^3)$) and solved it for $f''(x)$, it would still be 2nd-order accurate for calculating $f''(x)$, but you're right—dividing by $h^2$ to solve for $f''(x)$ reduces the $h^3$ in $\mathcal{O}(h^3)$ as well. *Thanks!*

Comment: @hardmath: My motivation is that my current research has data specified on a non-uniform grid. I don't have experience with turning non-uniform grids into uniform grids for finite difference schemes. While the grid is nearly logarithmic (which may provide an easy transformation scheme), it isn't perfectly logarithmic, so the grid spacing would still be irregular even on a log scale. An additional motivation is that this seems intellectually useful and interesting, and I haven't found an answer anywhere else! :-)

Comment: @hardmath: I'm not sure what you mean by "a product of two non-uniform one-dimensional spacings". Product in what sense? (My actual grid is sort of like $x_i \sim A exp( -B i)$, but with some additional random-ish variations in actual grid point locations.)

Comment: Okay, so it's just a one-dimensional "grid"?

Comment: @hardmath: Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You formula for the uniform grid is only of the first order. 
$$
\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h^2} - \frac{2}{h}f'(0) = f''(0) + \frac{h}{3} f'''(0) + O(h^2).
$$
It is not possible to construct a formula of the second order using $f(0), f'(0)$ and $f(h)$. Indeed:
$$
\frac{A}{h} f'(0) + \frac{B f(h) + C f(0)}{h^2} = 
\frac{B + C}{h^2} f(0) + \frac{A + B}{h} f'(0) + \frac{B}{2} f''(0) + 
\frac{Bh}{6} f'''(0) + O(h^2).
$$
Solving
$$
B + C = 0\\
A + B = 0\\
B = 2\\
$$
gives the only one possible formula and that is of $O(h)$ order.

For the irregular grid (assuming $h_i = O(h)$, i.e. $h$ is some average stepsize) let $\alpha = \frac{h_1}{h} = O(1)$, $\beta = \frac{h_1 + h_2}{h} = O(1)$, $\gamma = \frac{h_1 + h_2 + h_3}{h} = O(1)$
$$
\frac{A}{h} f'(0) + 
\frac{Bf(0) + Cf(\alpha h) + D f(\beta h) + E f(\gamma h)}{h^2} = \\
= \frac{B+ C+ D+ E}{h^2} f(0) 
+ \frac{A + \alpha C + \beta D + \gamma E}{h} f'(0)+\\
+ \frac{\alpha^2 C + \beta^2 D + \gamma^2 E}{2} f''(0)+
\frac{\alpha^3 C + \beta^3 D + \gamma^3 E}{6} hf'''(0)+
O(h^2).
$$
Now the second order conditions are
$$
B + C + D + E = 0\\
A + \alpha C + \beta D + \gamma E = 0\\
\alpha^2 C + \beta^2 D + \gamma^2 E = 2\\
\alpha^3 C + \beta^3 D + \gamma^3 E = 0\\
$$
These conditions have one more degree of freedom that can be used either for third order accurate formula, or for elimination of $f_4$ ($E = 0$), or for some other properties. In any case, the solution is
$$
A = 2\frac{\gamma  (\alpha
   -\gamma ) (\gamma -\beta
   )}{\alpha  \beta }E -2\frac{\alpha
   +\beta }{\alpha  \beta }\\
C = 2\frac{\beta }{\alpha ^2 (\beta
   -\alpha )}+2\frac{\gamma ^2
    (\beta -\gamma)}{\alpha ^2 (\alpha -\beta )}E\\
D = 2\frac{\alpha }{\beta ^2 (\alpha
   -\beta )}+2\frac{\gamma ^2 (\gamma -\alpha
   )}{\beta ^2 (\alpha -\beta )}E\\
B = -C - D - E
$$
For $E = 0, \alpha = 1, \beta = 2$ we get the formula for the uniform grid
$$
f''(0) = -\frac{3}{h}f'(0) + \frac{-7f(0) + 8f(h) -f(2h)}{2h^2} + O(h^2)
$$

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks! I'm processing your answer still, but one question: is there a name for your approach with the lettered coefficients? I've seen it before, and it looks powerful. I'd like to get more comfortable using it myself.

Comment: @jvriesem It is called the method of undetermined coefficients.

Comment: The second to last term of the big equation you have is: $\frac{\alpha^2 C + \beta^2 D + \gamma^2 E}{6} hf'''(0)$. Shouldn't it instead be $\frac{\alpha^3 C + \beta^3 D + \gamma^3 E}{6} hf'''(0)$?

Comment: @jvriesem Fixed, thank you

Comment: What's the version of the uniform grid's 2nd order expression for $i=N$, *i.e.* on the opposite boundary, for $f''(x_N)$? I think I got it, but you seem to know this solid. :-)

Comment: How would the 3rd order accurate scheme arise?

Comment: Just add one more equation zeroing $O(h^2)$ that is $\alpha^4 C +\beta^4 D+\gamma^4 E=0$

Comment: Hello @uranix !!! Could I ask you something about an elliptic problem? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31573/boundary-conditions

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with finite differences a lot recently and wrote a Mathematica script to do the method of undetermined coefficients. I stuck it on my [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iailh9pgwwhj2wz/StackOverflow.nb?dl=0).

The solution for $i = 1$ is:

$$f''(x_1) = -\frac{2 \left(\delta _2 \delta _3+\delta _4 \delta _3+\delta _2 \delta _4\right) }{\delta _2 \delta _3 \delta _4}f'\left(x_1\right) -\frac{2 \left(\delta _3^2 \delta _2^2+\delta _4^2 \delta _2^2+\delta _3 \delta _4 \delta _2^2+\delta _3 \delta _4^2 \delta _2+\delta _3^2 \delta _4 \delta _2+\delta _3^2 \delta _4^2\right)}{\delta _2^2 \delta _3^2 \delta _4^2} f\left(x_1\right) + \frac{2 \delta_3 \delta_4}{\delta _2^2 \left(\delta _2-\delta _3\right) \left(\delta _2-\delta _4\right)}f\left(x_2\right) - \frac{2 \delta _2 \delta _4 }{\delta _3^2 \left(\delta_2-\delta _3\right) \left(\delta _3-\delta _4\right)} f\left(x_3\right) + \frac{2 \delta_2 \delta_3 }{\delta _4^2 \left(\delta_3-\delta_4\right) \left(\delta_2 - \delta_4 \right)} f\left(x_4\right) + \mathcal{O}\left( \delta_2 \delta_3 \delta_4 \right) $$